# Use VBA to run a Python Script

Tags: python, vba

I'm trying to run a python script through VBA and shell function. Below is my VBA code

```
Private Sub Script()

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1


MyFile = "C:\Desktop\cmdcode.bat"
fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
Print #fnum, "cd C:\Desktop\"
Print #fnum, "python CreatePPT.py"
Close #fnum


' Run bat-file:
wsh.Run MyFile, windowStyle, waitOnReturn


' optional, remove bat-file:
Kill "C:\Desktop\cmdcode.bat"

End Sub
```

I think I was able to call cmd, it couldn't run my python script.

Below is the cmd window called using the shell function (I'm new to Stackoverflow and it doesn't allow me to embed images before I hit certain reputation. My apologizes)

[cmd window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzW6f.png)

Below is the cmd window called from my start menu

[cmd window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc4k4.png)

Looks like there are difference between these 2 cmd windows, and the first one wasn't able to execute my python script, while the second one was working fine.

Any insights what could be the reasons? thanks!

Comment: "enter image description here" - please take a minute to [edit] your post and embed the code (then select it all and hit Ctrl+K to indent the 4 spaces across all lines, that make it be formatted as a code block) and the commands *in the post itself*. Screen readers and people that don't or can't download from i.stack.imgur only see "enter image description here"..

Comment: On my end this code with path adjusted to C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\ works without issues, python script which was in my desktop folder has been successfully executed (it created a text file on desktop). You may want to try this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b3243c52-65d4-4fda-a7eb-f94733eaf408/how-to-trap-quotcmdexe-was-started-with-the-above-path-unc-paths-are-not-supported-quot?forum=ITCG

Comment: Thanks Ryszard, adding the line "pathd pushd %~dp0" to my bat file solves the issue.